# How to remove an item from a "collections.defaultdict"?

Tags: python

I have a `collections.defaultdict` as follows:

```
mydict = defaultdict(lambda:0)
mydict['stock1'] = 1.11
mydict['stock2'] = 2.22
mydict['stock3'] = 3.33
```

Now I want to remove the second item completely, how can I do that?

Maybe there is little seens to remove that but just simply set it to zero as follow:

```
mydict['stock2'] = 0
```

Comment: `del mydict['stock2']` and `defaultdict(int)` will also provide a default of `0`

Comment: `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`. Just use the same syntax as you would on a regular dictionary. `del mydict['stock2']` for example, or `mydict.pop('stock2')` if you want the value returned at the same time.

Comment: Note that you don't need to be using a `defaultdict` at all in your example.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[See the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), it's just like the ordinary dictionary. You can use either:

- `del mydict['stock2']`
- `mydict.pop('stock2')`