# Removing multiple entries from a python collection

Tags: python, collections

I am trying to remove multiple entries from my collections Counter, however I get a TypeError.

```
sentence="Hello 123 Bye 456"
letters = collections.Counter(sentence)
ignore=[' ','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
if ignore in letters:
    del letters[ignore]
```

But I get an error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Have looked at [How to remove an item from a "collections.defaultdict"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122926/how-to-remove-an-item-from-a-collections-defaultdict)

Comment: What is `sentence` ?

Comment: you've written `if ignore in letters:` That's like writing `if some_list_here in some_dict`. You need to pick either 1 key at a time and delete if its in the list, or pick either 1 item from the list at a time and delete if it matches a key.

Comment: Why do you think `if list in dict:` does not throw an error?

Answer (score 2):

It's better to keep count of only what you require in the first place than creating the entire count and deleting what is not required:

```
import collections

sentence = "Hello 123 Bye 456"
ignore = [' ','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

letters = collections.Counter(x for x in sentence if x not in ignore)

print(letters)
# Counter({'e': 2, 'l': 2, 'H': 1, 'o': 1, 'B': 1, 'y': 1})
```